# How can I change an appengine application's billing administrator?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to change the billing administrator of an appengine application. How can I achieve that without causing service disruption?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The administrator-to-be-billed needs to initiate this from the admin console. See [Changing the Billing Administrator](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Changing_the_Billing_Administrator).